# A large array to be handled in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, caching, cookies

I have a large array at hand (2300 elements, 280 KB in total, 180 KB in shortest form). I need to handle it either in PHP or JavaScript without loading the page or server too much. There is an autocomplete field in the page and I don't want it to send request to a 180 KB page every time a user types in a letter (as it seems to be highly inefficient to me). I don't want to store all that in the original page 'coz it would slow the page down (wouldn't it?).

I tried to push it into the Cookies, but it seems that there is no room for such huge array in the Cookies. Any suggestions? Perhaps searching within a database is better solution and I should store them in the database instead?

Comment: Using a database for autocomplete fields is a classical solution indeed. It works very well. Never send to the client the complete list, it's useless and this solution wouldn't scale.

Comment: I thinks you must use JSON+PHP for this.
this will just a little request and fetch your data

Comment: I have previously done stuff with a javascript array with about 81,000 elements to it. Th eonly problem was that it crashed when I tried access the length property like so: `array.length`.

Comment: @dystroy : Database solution seems to be the most logical one to me too, but I was hoping there is a way to cache the values somehow and don't send a longy string from the server and instead send a tiny element key number.

Comment: @Basic Bridge : This is what I am already doing. Just I want to cache the static array somehow.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs : My major problem is loading the same array over and over. The performance shouldn't really be a problem, I hope!

Comment: I see your problem. Does the array completely change, or can you only send send differences?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs : The array changes considerably at the end of every 3-4 months. During that (3-4 month) period it stays constant.

Comment: You could possibly find a javascript checksum function and calculate the checksum of the JSON encoded array. Then you could send it to the server and if it matches, then the server can tell the client that there is no change. Otherwise, the server sends the updated array to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to autocomplete with a list that you load only one ? Store it in a JavaScript file and set the proper cache headers so clients only load the list once.

Do NOT set it as a cookie, that's just nonsense.

Comment: Yes, I need to load the list once (every 3-4 months, actually). Can you direct me to any resource with the information about **proper cache headers***, please? Are you talking about the following?

`Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT`

And, how can I make sure the browser deletes the cached version every time I have the newer version (every 3-4 months) on the server?

Comment: Look for documentation for your server, [this is the documentation for Apache 2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html). You'll find lots of documentation on this particular subject via google or here on StackOverflow. Give an unlimited cache lifetime for your file and change the path when you're updating it. Like list-rev1.js, then list-rev2.js, etc...

Comment: Oh and also, gzip it when the client supports it. Since it's a file containing text, you'll save a lot on bandwidth and speed up the loading of your pages.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe it is Actually Best to Send the input to the Server Through Ajax & wait for the Server-Side Reply if you are concerned about Page Loading times + If your Array is Changing from time to time...

On the Other hand you could store the array in JSON format in a fie on the server & issue it inside JavaScript Through Ajax, That way your user will have to download the array once & later you can rely of the browser cache to speed it up.

eg.

```
$.get("array.txt",function(array){

   var myArray = eval(array);
   //Now DO WHat YOu WAnt with the Array now Housed in the variable 'myArray'

});
```

THis is Just an Example, it is not nessecery for you to use jQuery.

**Note:-**

If you use the second method...Its Best to add some sort of buffer
    mechanism so that your users wait for it to load the first time a
    user visits the site in their current session. This is just so that
    users get what they expect on first try or else they might not see
    any suggestions or whatever you want to do with the array then
    they'll get irritated & eventually leave.

You Need to Set the correct Cache Header if using PHP. Normally a
    txt file that you upload once & never change will automatically be
    sent to Cache in most Modern Browsers.

Comment: Array does not change a lot - only once in 3-4 months. Also, I am already using jquery, sending information in JSON format. The actual queries (both requests and replies) are tiny, just I don't want to have the server process same array over and over again. The problem about caching, I want to be able to send the newer list to the users when I have it. Is there any way of checking this without relying on timing thing?

Answer (score 0):

Using a database for autocomplete fields is a classical solution indeed. I think that you wouldn't have difficulty finding a PHP/mysql/jquery autocomplete tutorial.

It works very well.

Never send to the client the complete list, it's useless and this solution wouldn't scale when your number of values grows.

Comment: I can do the trick with database as well, just I was not sure it is the best option. Also, I don't send over 10 elements to the client, but thanks for noting that one too.

Comment: That's clearly the best option, and the most used, especially when using PHP.

Comment: Depends on the size of the database. If it fits in 280kB (divide by 3 or 4 using gzip), you'll save on CPU usage by sending the entire list to your users. And it's a beter UX since it autocompletes instantly. Voyages-sncf.com (french rail reservation system, 11 million unique visitors / month) uses this to autocomplete the train stations.